# Ошибка: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (2,)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Ошибка:

```
w1[0, :]=w1[0, :]-np.array(x[0:3])*delta3[0]*lmd
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (2,)
```

Что не так?

```
#стартовые веса для слоев
w1=np.array([[-0.5, 1, 0.5], [-0.5, 1, 0.5]])
w2=np.array([[0.5, -0.5],[0.5, -0.5]])
w3=np.array([0.5, -0.5])
#персептрон 3/2/2/1
def go(inp):
     t=np.dot(w1, inp)
     n1=np.array([f(x) for x in t])
     t2=np.dot(w2, n1)
     n2=np.array([f(x) for x in t2])
     t3=np.dot(w3, n2)
     y=f(t3)
     return (y, n1, n2)
#тренировка обратным распространением
def train(epoch):
     global w3, w2, w1
     lmd=0.01
     N=20000
     count=len(epoch)
     for k in range(N):
          x=epoch[np.random.randint(0, count)]
          y, n1, n2=go(x[0:3])
          e=y-x[-1]
#корректировка весов связей последнего (выходного) 
слоя
          delta=e*df(y)
          w3[0]=w3[0]-n2[0]*delta*lmd
          w3[1]=w3[1]-n2[1]*delta*lmd
#коррекция весов связей среднего (скрытого) слоя
          delta2=w3*delta*df(n2)
          w2[0]=w2[0]-np.array(n1[0])*delta2[0]*lmd
          w2[1]=w2[1]-np.array(n1[1])*delta2[0]*lmd
          w2[0]=w2[0]-np.array(n1[0])*delta2[1]*lmd
          w2[1]=w2[1]-np.array(n1[1])*delta2[1]*lmd
#корректировка весов связей первого (входного) слоя
          delta3=w2*delta2*df(n1)
          w1[0, :]=w1[0, :]-np.array(x[0:3])*delta3[0]*lmd
          w1[1, :]=w1[1, :]-np.array(x[0:3])*delta3[1]*lmd
```

Answer (score 1):

Судя по ошибке, вы пытаетесь перемножить две 1D матрицы, состоящие из единственной строки, причем строки в этих двух матрицах разной длины. Так делать нельзя.

Воспроизведение ошибки:

```
In [42]: np.array([1,2,3]) * np.array([2,4])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-ed7f5e5a5a15> in <module>
----> 1 np.array([1,2,3]) * np.array([2,4])

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (2,)
```

Вместо этого можно умножать 1D одномерную матрицу, состоящую из единственной **строки**, на 1D матрицу, состоящую из единственной **столбца**:

```
In [43]: np.array([1,2,3]) * np.array([[2],[4]])
Out[43]:
array([[ 2,  4,  6],
       [ 4,  8, 12]])
```

или наоборот:

```
In [44]: np.array([[2],[4]]) * np.array([1,2,3])
Out[44]:
array([[ 2,  4,  6],
       [ 4,  8, 12]])
```

Comment: Когда отсутствует второй - средний - слой нейронов (3/2/1), эта запись не вызывает ошибки: два нейрона принимают три входных значения - три связи на каждый нейрон. Тут какая-то ошибка в записи корректировки весов второго слоя, какая не знаю. Но если наличие второго слоя изменяет запись третьего, то как ее изменить в коде?

Comment: @RZorge, я извиняюсь, но у меня нет никакого желания разбираться в этом "фееричном" коде :-D Я показал вам суть ошибки и как ее исправить, а дальше попробуйте исправить свой код так, чтобы у вас не возникала такая ситуация...

Comment: два нейрона принимают массив трехзначных матриц.

Comment: и на том спасибо. Но, замечу, как только что-то не склеилось, так сразу код "фееричный". Хотя Вы в нем не разобрались :)

Comment: @RZorge, [я немного представляю как работают простые нейронные сети](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8/topusers), но ваш код написан так, что отбивает желание в нем разбираться ;) __Hint__: представьте что вам понадобится подать на вход матрицу другой размерности или добавить несколько скрытых слоев - это же весь код каждый раз переписывать придется...

Comment: код написан почти замечательно (немного не так, как мне бы хотелось) за исключением куска корректировки весов. Я полный профан в корректном написании индексов, код корректировки весов среднего слоя написал тупо пытаясь найти закономерности. Хочу, чтобы мне написали правильный кусочек кода корректировки весов среднего слоя при обратном распространении ошибки в персептроне 3/2/2/1. Для знающего человека - задача несложная.

Comment: согласен, что, если бы, я привел обозначение в коде функции активации и ее производной, массив тренировочных данных, а вместо t, n писал, например, out_values, int_values и т.п., код был бы понятней стороннему человеку...

Comment: @RZorge, возможно здесь найдутся люди, которые __захотят__ написать этот кусочек кода. ;)